# Magento2.1 image importer

Tags: magento-2.1, product-images, import, image-upload

I want to import images into magento2.1 with default importer.

My problem is that I added image folder into pub like this:

> pub/media/catelectronicpic/mobile/1.jpg
>
> pub/media/catelectronicpic/laptop/1.jpg

but after import, all the images in front-end are same, it shows 1.jpg for all products

Answer (score 0):

Please try with default format something wrong with your Images File Directory, for more details check with below url.

https://amasty.com/knowledge-base/how-to-import-product-images-into-magento-2.html

https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/data-import-product-images.html

Comment: I know it but i have 12000 images who are in separated folders as i described above. but most of them has same name at the end. what should i do?